# Book: Ron Larson, Calculus, Find the Limit if it exists?

Tags: calculus, limits

I answered a question to determine whether a particular limit of a function exists and I got the right answer that it didn’t exist but for a different reason to what the book states.

**Question.** Find the limit (if it exists) and if it does not exist explain why.

$$\lim_{x\to-3^-}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}\right)$$

**My answer.** The domain is restricted to the closed interval $[-3 , 3]$.
The limit does not exist because the function is only continuous on the right-hand side of $x=3$.

**Books Solution.** The limit does not exist. The function decreases without bound as $x$ approaches $-3$ from the left.

Can someone please explain if my solution would suffice and also what the book means by this, since I thought that the function was undefinded for values of $x<-3$?

Answer (score 6):

The domain is not $[-3,3].$ The domain is

$$\left\{x: x^2 >9\right\}=(-\infty, -3) \cup (3, \infty).$$

We have

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-9}} \to - \infty$$

as $x \to -3^-$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that he asks you to compute the left-sided limit
$$
\lim_{x \to - 3^-} f(x)
$$
where $f$ is the expression of the function. Notice the $-$ as an exponent of the $3$. Therefore your solution doesn't suffice. The book is correct: the limit "is" $- \infty$, so it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

To find the interval where the function is defined notice that we need $x^2>9$, that is $x\in (-\infty,-3)\cup (3,\infty)$.

To see why it grows without bound write $ f(-3-\epsilon)=\frac{-3-\epsilon}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2+6\epsilon}}$ for $\epsilon >0$. Do you see why this grows to $-\infty$ as $\epsilon$ decreases?

Comment: yes . My domain was completely off . Thanks